# Redis cluster integration with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-boot, redis

I have a **redis cluster with master, slave and 3 sentinel servers**. The master and slave is map to dns names as node1-redis-dev.com,  node2-redis-dev.com. The redis server version is 2.8

I include below in my application.properties file.

```
spring.redis.cluster.nodes=node1-redis-dev.com:6379,node2-redis-dev.com:6379
spring.redis.pool.max-idle=8
spring.redis.pool.min-idle=0
spring.redis.pool.max-active=-1
spring.redis.pool.max-wait=-1
```

But when I inspect the StringRedisTemplate, **I see localhost instead of cluster information under hostName property** of JedisConnectionFactory.

Also I see the exception in creationStackTrace property of JedisPool.

```
java.lang.Exception
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.BaseGenericObjectPool.<init>(BaseGenericObjectPool.java:139)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.<init>(GenericObjectPool.java:107)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.initPool(Pool.java:43)
    at redis.clients.util.Pool.<init>(Pool.java:31)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.<init>(JedisPool.java:80)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.<init>(JedisPool.java:74)
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.<init>(JedisPool.java:55)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createRedisPool(JedisConnectionFactory.java:228)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.createPool(JedisConnectionFactory.java:204)
```

[image: Debug information]

The CasheRepository class looks like below,

```
@Component
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "enroll", cacheManager = "enrollCM")
public class EnrollCashRepository {
    @Autowired
    private StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate;    
    //Other methods 
}
```

I am using spring boot 1.3.4 with spring-boot-starter-redis 1.2.7 which import jedis 2.7.3 dependency.

What am I missing with integrate redis cluster with Spring boot applicatiom?

Comment: How you are configuring Cache?

Comment: @Arpit Like when configure single node in property file, cluster also configure in there. No other special configuration

Comment: can you show your configuration file?

Comment: Redis Sentinel is not Redis Cluster.

Comment: @Arpit Its the application.properties I post in the question

Comment: show us the complete error trace.

Answer (score 7):

All that is needed is setting the initial collection of cluster nodes in RedisClusterConfiguration and provide that one to JedisConnectionFactory.

```
@Configuration
class Config {

    List<String> clusterNodes = Arrays.asList("node1-redis-dev.com:6379", "node2-redis-dev.com:6379");

    @Bean
    RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
      return new JedisConnectionFactory(new RedisClusterConfiguration(clusterNodes));
    }

    @Bean
    RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {

      // just used StringRedisTemplate for simplicity here.
      return new StringRedisTemplate(factory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding cluster nodes in property file in not enough?

Comment: configuration through only properties file will work with @EnableAutoConfiguration if you use latest version of spring boot.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#_enabling_redis_cluster

Comment: I use @SpringBootApplication

Comment: Spring boot 1.3.4 has issue with redis cluster configuration from application.properties, either you upgrade to latest spring boot version to use it from properties or use java configuration. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way i add above code but i get below error when application start. "JedisDataException: ERR unknown command 'CLUSTER'". I add jedis 2.9.0 jar too in my pom. Any idea please?

Comment: Thanks. Could you please share the reference or link of that fact. I was not able to find it in documentation.

Comment: Also I notice jedis jar 2.9 has ClusterCommands.class in root level and from 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT its move to a package name cluster. But that information is not relevant to your comment I guess.

Comment: this may help, http://serverfault.com/questions/690875/upgrading-from-redis-2-8-19-to-3-0-1. i will suggest to migrate to latest redis version

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess according to my set up I should use RedisSentinelConfiguration instead of RedisClusterConfiguration know.

Answer (score 5):

The following should work

application.properties

```
spring.redis.cluster.nodes=127.0.0.1:6379
spring.redis.cluster.max-redirects=3
```

ClusterConfigurationProperties.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.redis.cluster")
public class ClusterConfigurationProperties {

/*
 * spring.redis.cluster.nodes[0] = 127.0.0.1:7379 spring.redis.cluster.nodes[1]
 * = 127.0.0.1:7380 ...
 */
private List<String> nodes;
/**
 * spring.redis.cluster.max-redirects=3
 */
private int maxRedirects;

/**
 * Get initial collection of known cluster nodes in format {@code host:port}.
 *
 * @return
 */
public List<String> getNodes() {
    return nodes;
}

public void setNodes(List<String> nodes) {
    this.nodes = nodes;
}

public int getMaxRedirects() {
    return maxRedirects;
}

public void setMaxRedirects(int maxRedirects) {
    this.maxRedirects = maxRedirects;
}

}
```

RedisConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisClusterConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;

import io.lettuce.core.ReadFrom;

@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

@Autowired
private ClusterConfigurationProperties clusterProperties;

@Bean
LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(RedisClusterConfiguration redisConfiguration) {

    LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
            .readFrom(ReadFrom.REPLICA_PREFERRED).build();

    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConfiguration, clientConfig);
}

@Bean
RedisClusterConfiguration redisConfiguration() {
    RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration(clusterProperties.getNodes());
    redisClusterConfiguration.setMaxRedirects(clusterProperties.getMaxRedirects());

    return redisClusterConfiguration;
}

@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "redisTemplate")
@Primary
RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    // other settings...
    return template;
}
}
```

Comment: upvote, its works, tested in redis 2 latest spring boot and jdk 11

Comment: hi，you can get redis properties from RedisProperties, no need to add ClusterConfigurationProperties