# Can't connect to redis service on kubernetes using jedis

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I have a k8s cluster with a redis service and a java service, both in the same namespace. The redis pod gets created, I can port forward it and connect using redis-cli, also tried creating a pod with a busybox image just to try pring and `telnet redis 6379`, both works. However, using my java service to connect does not work. Any ideas on why that could be happening? Maybe its some redis configuration.

I get this error

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
```

using on the service:

```java
public void test() {
    final JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = buildPoolConfig();
    JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool("redis", 6379);
    try(Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
        jedis.set( "somekey", "somevalue" );
    }
}
```

And here is my redis service yaml file

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: redis
data:
  redis-config: |
    maxmemory 2mb
    maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis
  clusterIP: None

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: redis:6.2.6
        name: redis
        command:
          - redis-server
          - "/redis-master/redis.conf"
        env:
          - name: MASTER
            value: "true"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 6379
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 300Mi
            cpu: 800m
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /redis-master-data
            name: data
          - mountPath: /redis-master
            name: config
      volumes:
      - name: data
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: redis
          items:
            - key: redis-config
              path: redis.conf
```

Comment: Are both apps in the same namespace?

Comment: yes, they are in the same namespace

Comment: Please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64184121/2777988

Comment: Can you check the IP that your app resolved with "redis" is the cluster IP of your redis master pod?

Comment: Can you include the output of `kubectl get pods --selector=app=redis`

Comment: can it be jedis version incompatibility with redis server version?