# Using JedisCluster with RedisTemplate in Spring

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, redis, jedis, cluster-mode

Originally in our code we were using `RedisTemplate` in conjuction with `JedisConnectionFactory` and `JedisPoolConfig` as we were using a Redis on a single node:

```
   @Bean(name = "redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> getRedisTemplate(JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate template = new RedisTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
        // ...
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory(Configuration config) {
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName(config.get(HOST));
        jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(config.getInt(PORT));
        jedisConnectionFactory.setUsePool(true);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setPoolConfig(createJedisPoolConfig(config));
        jedisConnectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }

    JedisPoolConfig createJedisPoolConfig(Config config) {
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        // ...
        return poolConfig;
    }
```

We are now using `JedisCluster` as we are using a Redis cluster.

When we used RedisTemplate we used a number of commands such as `redisTemplate.hasKey(cacheKey)` to check if the key exists and `redisTemplate.opsForValue().set` among many others relevant to `RedisTemplate`.

These methods don't appear to be available for `JedisCluster`.

**Is there a way I can use RedisTemplate in conjunction with JedisCluster to avoid re-coding these methods and just utilise the methods RedisTemplate offers?**

**Or are there alternative commands that can be used in place of the ones offered by RedisTemplate?**

Comment: Thank you so much @ErmiyaEskandary. I got it working. You are an absolute legend! Both approaches worked fine but I ended up using the one in the stackoverflow comment you mentioned to minimalise the code change required.

Comment: You're more than welcome! Make sure to upvote the other answer if it helped and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> s there a way I can use RedisTemplate in conjunction with JedisCluster to avoid re-coding these methods and just utilise the methods RedisTemplate offers?

Yes, refer to this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41918747/4800344).

> Or are there alternative commands that can be used in place of the ones offered by RedisTemplate?

For future reference, also yes.

`RedisTemplate.hasKey(cacheKey)` is an interface to the Redis EXISTS command.

`JedisCluster.exists(cacheKey)` is the equivalent.

`RedisTemplate.opsForValue().set()` is an interface to [operations on strings](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html#opsForValue--).

`JedisCluster.set("key", "value")` is the equivalent.

Use the RedisTemplate docs to figure out the Redis command being used and then map it to the equivalent in Jedis using their documentation.

A search in your favourite search engine for "Redis [COMMAND] in Jedis" should get you what you need.